# How to convert or load saved model into TensorFlow or Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I used tensorflow keras to create a model and defined a callback to save the model after each epoch. It worked and saved the model in `pb` format but I cannot load it again into keras because keras just accept `h5` format.

I have two questions:

- Except tensorflow serving how I can load my saved model into keras/tensorflow?
- How I can save a keras model after each epoch in `h5` format?

My callback and saving the model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_freq= 'epoch', verbose=1 )

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

My saved model structure:

```
saved_trained_10_epochs
├── assets
├── saved_model.pb
└── variables
    ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
    └── variables.index
```

### Update

I tried to use `latest_checkpoint` as below but got below errors:

```
from tensorflow.train import latest_checkpoint

loaded_model = latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path)
loaded_model.summary()
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-76a8ebe4f259> in <module>
----> 1 loaded_model.summary()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

And after recreating the model:

```
loaded_regressor = Sequential()

loaded_regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 3)))
loaded_regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

loaded_regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
loaded_regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

loaded_regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
loaded_regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

loaded_regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
loaded_regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

loaded_regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
loaded_regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

loaded_regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180))
loaded_regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

loaded_regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

loaded_regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
loaded_regressor.load_weights(latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path))
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-c344f1759d01> in <module>
     22 
     23 loaded_regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
---> 24 loaded_regressor.load_weights(latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
    160         raise ValueError('Load weights is not yet supported with TPUStrategy '
    161                          'with steps_per_run greater than 1.')
--> 162     return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
    163 
    164   @trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
   1375             format.
   1376     """
-> 1377     if _is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
   1378       save_format = 'h5'
   1379     else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _is_hdf5_filepath(filepath)
   1670 
   1671 def _is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
-> 1672   return (filepath.endswith('.h5') or filepath.endswith('.keras') or
   1673           filepath.endswith('.hdf5'))
   1674 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to load the model?

Comment: Why aren't you using tf.keras.models.load_model to load your model?

Comment: Because `latest_checkpoint` was the suggested method in the official documentation for saving and loading models during training and after that I checked the Keras github repo and converting the pb to h5 was an open issue there. I tried your suggestion and that worked, thank you. Please post it as a separate answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.keras` models are loaded using `tf.keras.models.load_model`, this should work fine as `tf.keras` supports reading/writing multiple formats, including tensorflow checkpoints.

Comment: I tried with `tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/ambigus9/models/research/my_model/exported_models/saved_model/')` and got `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`, any idea why?

Comment: I have the same issue. TensorFlow 2.3.1

Comment: I opened a new question for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105594/keras-failed-to-load-savedmodel-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Comment: ValueError: Unable to create a Keras model from this SavedModel. This SavedModel was created with `tf.saved_model.save`, and lacks the Keras metadata.Please save your Keras model by calling `model.save`or `tf.keras.models.save_model`.

Comment: @Ark-kun Please don't post random error messages without any context.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I thought that the error message is self-describing and the question and the answer provides enough context. Could you please help me help you understand the error message? The answer proposes to use `tf.keras.models.load_model` to load TF SavedModels. However, `tf.keras.models.load_model` cannot load TF SavedModels as indicated by the error message. The error message is part of the official TensorFlow Keras source code. Not all TF Keras SavedModels can be loaded using `tf.keras.models.load_model`.

Comment: @Ark-kun did you find a solution to this error?