# Keras failed to load SavedModel: TypeError 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I trained an SSD MobileNet v2 network using the [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) with TensorFlow 2 and then converted the trained model into a SavedModel. Now I need to **convert the SavedModel to a FrozenGraph** in order to make the model compatible with external libraries like OpenCV. I use [this example](https://medium.com/@sebastingarcaacosta/how-to-export-a-tensorflow-2-x-keras-model-to-a-frozen-and-optimized-graph-39740846d9eb) for conversion and I cannot even load the Keras model.

```python
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("training/model/saved_model")
```

Calling `load_model()` produces an exception:

```text
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'module' object is not callable

Full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\saved_model_to_frozen_graph.py", line 17, in <module>
    model = load_model("saved_model")
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 187, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 121, in load
    path, options=options, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 633, in load_internal
    ckpt_options)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 194, in __init__
    super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 130, in __init__
    self._load_all()
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 221, in _load_all
    self._finalize_objects()
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 530, in _finalize_objects
    self._reconstruct_all_models()
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 548, in _reconstruct_all_models
    self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 589, in _reconstruct_model
    config, created_layers={layer.name: layer for layer in layers})
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1215, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1163, in process_node
    output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 926, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1117, in _functional_construction_call
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 903, in call
    result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "path\to\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 205, in wrapper
    result = dispatch(wrapper, args, kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

type(layer) = <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Lambda'>
```

Anyone knows how to fix that?

---

Additional information:

Windows 10, Python 3.7, TensorFlow 2.3.1, Keras 2.4.3

```text
# Train the network
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir="training" --pipeline_config_path="training/pipeline.config"
# Export the network
python exporter_main_v2.py --input_type=image_tensor --pipeline_config_path="training/pipeline.config" --trained_checkpoint_dir="training" --output_directory="training/model"
```

Folder structure:

```text
training/
-> label_map.pbtxt
-> pipeline.config
-> model
 . -> checkpoint
 . -> saved_model
 .  . -> assets
 .  . -> variables
 .  . -> saved_model.pb
-> checkpoint
-> ckpt.x.data-00000-of-00001
-> ckpt.x.index
```

Comment: Well, what do you think "callable" means? Can you relate that to the line of code where the error is reported? What do you think is the "module object" that the error message refers to? Does it make sense to you that this is in fact a module object? What kinds of things are normally "callable"? Did you expect the object to be one of those, instead? Now - try to *read the documentation* and see if it explains any better.

Comment: You should include the full traceback, not part of it.

Comment: `keras.models.load_model` is a module, not a function. I'm unfamiliar with the library you're using so I don't know what's the correct import statement, but try: `from keras.models.load_model import load_model`.

Comment: I included the full traceback now. The import statement seems to be ok. `from keras.models.load_model import load_model` produces an error: `No module named 'keras.models.load_model'; 'keras.models' is not a package`

Comment: `load_model()` should accept the model path if properly given. Here is the reference of this module (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model). Make sure your didn't create any other variable with the same name (`load_model`).

Comment: I have only the import and the function call in my testing script, so no other variables. `from keras.models import load_model as lm` gives the same error. I think that it has something to do with a certain layer of the NN which can't be interpreted. The first two layers are working ('tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D' and 'load.FreezableBatchNorm'), the third layer ('tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Lambda') not.

Comment: Loading the same model with `tf.saved_model.load()` works fine but doesn't help to convert it to FrozenGraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to convert the model without Keras, which is working for me.
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16879

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

loaded = tf.saved_model.load('training/model/saved_model')
infer = loaded.signatures['serving_default']

f = tf.function(infer).get_concrete_function(input_tensor=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, None, None, 3], dtype=tf.uint8))
f2 = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(f)
graph_def = f2.graph.as_graph_def()

# Export frozen graph
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('frozen_graph.pb', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be the lambda layer in your model.

There are some issues in Keras that may raise `TypeError(str is not callable or module is not callable)` while loading a model with lambda layer.

To solve the issue, not save the model with model.save. Instead, save the model weights and recreate the model architecture using the code,then load weights.

Example：

```
model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

or

```
ModelCheckPoint(file,save_weights_only=True)#this will call save_weights
```

After create the model,then:

```
model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

**Note:**
save the model architecture as a JSON file can't solve the error